# Vulkan: Why does the 1080 Ti have a maxMemoryAllocationCount of 4294967296 on arch but only 4096 on Windows?

Tags: c++, gpu, vulkan

I am currently building a game engine in C++ which uses vulkan for rendering. While implementing a terrain renderer I reached a hardware limit, the maxMemoryAllocationCount which limits the amount of allocated memory blocks. I checked https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/ to see how high that value on different GPUs is. When looking at the "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti", the value is 4096 for windows but 4294967296 for arch/manjaro. Why is there a difference between those OSes, when this really *should* be a hardware limitation?

Comment: `4294967296` is 2^32. `maxMemoryAllocationCount` is `uint32_t` which can hold values between `0` and `4294967295`/`2^32-1`. So the value is most likely just garbage.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: It's not garbage. It means "as many as you want".

Comment: 4096 memory allocations is quite a big number. If You hit this limit, this means You should allocate smaller number of much larger memory objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why "should" it be a hardware limitation?

With 4 exceptions, every Windows implementation is limited to 4096 allocations. And those exceptions are either open-source RADV hacked to run on Windows or early drivers that returned bogus values.

So clearly, Windows as an OS is imposing this limitation. After all, the OS owns the GPU and must be involved in any memory allocations.

It is the right of the OS to prevent a process from engaging in pathological behavior. Windows seems to think that making lots of GPU allocations is pathological (and they're not wrong), so the WDDM model imposes a low-but-reasonable limit on GPU allocations.

Comment: That "should" part is because maxMemoryAllocationCount is part of the physical device limits. "Physical Device Limit" seems to be not that strict here.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: It's `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits`. As in, the limits for `VkPhysicalDevice`s. The words "physical device" has a specific meaning in Vulkan, and it has nothing to do with a specific piece of silicon.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher Graphics hardware (physical device) can only operate in an area defined by the operating system. So even if the silicon itself is capable of allocating much larger number of memory objects, it cannot do it if operating system doesn't allow for that. So in this case it doesn't even matter if it is a "real" hardware limitation or an OS constraint - this hardware/driver/OS combination forbids You to allocate more than 4096 memory objects.

Comment: I seriously doubt that Windows is deliberately preventing processes from making lots of GPU allocations over some vague notion of what constitutes "pathological behavior." It is far more likely that the limit on the number of allocations is a side-effect of whatever data structures Windows uses to keep track of GPU memory allocations. So it's more like "4096 should be enough" rather than "anything greater than 4096 would constitute pathological behavior." The fact that NVIDIA's own Linux driver has a much higher limit would appear to support this point.

Comment: @AdrianLopez: "*It is far more likely that the limit on the number of allocations is a side-effect of whatever data structures Windows uses to keep track of GPU memory allocations.*" And yet, Windows can and does make over 4096 GPU allocations. Just across different processes.

Comment: @AdrianLopez: "*The fact that NVIDIA's own Linux driver has a much higher limit would appear to support this point.*" No, it doesn't; [*all* non-Windows drivers have a higher limit](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=maxMemoryAllocationCount&platform=all). Indeed, the only Linux drivers with a limitation of 4096 are those that are [running on top of DX12](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?limit=maxMemoryAllocationCount&value=4096&platform=linux) in a Linux VM.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but the point is that NVIDIA *could* limit its drivers to allow a maximum of 4096 allocations per instance but doesn't. The fact that they and others don't do this suggests they don't care about preventing the kind of "pathological behavior" you speak of. It's likely just an implementation choice my Microsoft rather than a deliberate attempt to force programmers to write supposedly non-pathological code.

Comment: @AdrianLopez: NVIDIA won't get blamed if the OS crashes; *Microsoft* will. NVIDIA doesn't care about preventing pathological behavior because they *don't have to*. Windows Vista's initial release was considered extremely buggy, but a good portion of those bugs were due to buggy graphics drivers. But it wasn't IHVs who took the blame for it. Indeed, Microsoft has been making a lot of decisions that are all about protecting Windows from garbage programs. This is part of the reason for their push towards more memory safety in C++ as a language, for example.

Comment: @AdrianLopez: So yes, it would be 100% in character for Microsoft to add protections into WDDM to prevent an application from doing profoundly silly things. And it would be 100% in character for NVIDIA, AMD, and other IHVs to just not care and allow the OS to take the blame.

Comment: The fact that 4096 == 2^12 suggests to me that Microsoft is using a 12-bit representation associated with GPU memory allocations somewhere in the WDDM, and that this choice is just a matter of keeping kernel data structures as small as possible while still meeting the needs of application programmers. I'm not sure I see how allowing a higher number of allocations (say 2^30 like on macOS) would necessarily result in OS instability, nor why the limit would need to be a power of two if it were just a test for pathological behavior.