# Why Vulkan has a limit of memory allocations?

Tags: gpu, vulkan

Is there any technical reasons to limit the maximum number of memory allocations?

Check out [vkAllocateMemory manual page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkAllocateMemory.html). It says:

> The maximum number of valid memory allocations that can exist simultaneously within a VkDevice may be restricted by implementation- or platform-dependent limits. If a call to vkAllocateMemory would cause the total number of allocations to exceed these limits, such a call will fail and must return VK_ERROR_TOO_MANY_OBJECTS.

OpenGL doesn't limit allocations, DirectX 11/12 neither. So why should Vulkan do so?

Answer (score 13):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47313319/734069), this is primarily an OS limitation.

> OpenGL doesn't limit allocations, DirectX 11/12 neither

Oh, they do. They just don't *tell you* about it.

OpenGL and DX11 drivers tend to internally do large GPU (virtual) allocations and perform sub-allocations from those when you allocate memory. Thus, they can create the *illusion* that you can perform more hardware allocations. But the limitation is still there.

As for DX12, I'm fairly sure that if you try to allocate more than 4096 *heaps*, you will find `CreateHeap` returning errors.

Vulkan is simply the API that's up-front about the existence of the limitation.

With Vulkan, this is simply a problem that should never arise. If you're performing over a thousand individual memory allocations, your memory allocation scheme is wrong. You're *supposed* to allocate a few large slabs of memory, then use sub-sections of them for your textures and buffers.